# Are "Guess What the Developer was Thinking" type questions valid?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32696284/522444) and similar questions -- aren't they asking for opinion and not valid for this site? Thanks.

Comment: Of course they aren't valid. I'm closing often enough using _primarily opinion based_.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment to the original question there's no guessing involved. I see how this can create opinion-based comments and answers which require more moderation work, yet the question and the question's type in general (which we're discussing here - except for the title) doesn't read "Why did the devs do this and this? What do you think?".

Comment: @KarlRichter - Are you hoping the developers can answer you directly here or are you asking the SO community to go find an existing statement by the developers for you?

Comment: @BSMP The latter. A blog entry, public design paper, ... Does it make a difference? I wouldn't mind getting an original statement from the devs.

Comment: @KarlRichter _"... A blog entry, public design paper ..."_ Asking for off-site resources is off-topic as well.

Comment: @KarlRichter so it's not opinion based, but it is asking for external resources? still should be closed.

Comment: Yes to the former and I agree with the latter.